Does changing from one coordinate system to another involve loss of information in random variable transformation?
Suppose I have a complex random variable (not Gaussian) given as:
$$z=x+jy$$ where $x$ and $y$ are identically distributed random variables whose marginal PDFs are given by $f_\text{x}(x)$ and $f_\text{y}(y)$. I do not have any information about the dependency structure between random variables $x$ and $y$, neither do I have $f_{xy}(x,y)$, but I know  $f_\text{x}(x)$ and $f_\text{y}(y)$.
Now, I know it does not make any sense to have $Pr(Z\leq z)$ but I can have:
$$Pr(A\leq a)$$
$$Pr(\Theta\leq \theta)$$ where I define $A:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\Theta:=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$. However, the issue is since I do not know the joint distribution $f_{xy}(x,y)$, how can I apply the Jacobian for random variable transformation from Cartesian to polar Coordinate system. But ideally it should be possible, as I am just transforming the variables, and therefore no new information should be required.
Does changing from one coordinate system to another involves loss of information in random variable transformation?
I have linked this question to another question
PS: Let us assume that the marginal distributions of $A$ and $\theta$ are known and it is known that these two distributions are independent of one another, then I can find $x=A\cos\theta$ and $y=A\sin\theta$. Taking in the reverse direction. Suppose, If I know $A$ and $\theta$ are independent but no dependency of $x$ and $y$ are known, however the marginal PDFs of $x$ and $y$ are known then can I find PDF of $A$ and $\theta$?

It doesn't alter your question, but your use of the arctangent limits angles to a range of $\pi$ radians, although your $x+\mathrm{j}y$s can range over $2\pi$ radians.  You might prefer atan2 to get angles in all four quadrants.  There's still a problem when $x = y = 0$, since the argument is undefined at the origin, but that occurs with probability zero, right?

I don't think you can say much about the distribution of $A$ and $\Theta$ from just this information. Quick example: suppose $x$ and $y$ are standard normal distributed. If $x$ and $y$ are independent, then $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed. But we could also have strong correlation, say that always $x=y$. Then $\Theta$ can only have two values: $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$.

@Matthew Spam Exactly my point if I know $A$ and $\Theta$, I can derive distribution of $x=A\sin \theta$ and $y=A\cos\theta$, But why the reverse is not possible?

To get $x$ and $y$ from $A$ and $\Theta$ you'd also need to know how $A$ and $\Theta$ depend on each other.

What you want to do is simply not possible. If you do not have any information about $f_{xy}(x,y)$, there is no way you can correctly calculate the transformation.
Let's make a simple problem: How to calculate the probability distribution of the sum $x+y$ of 2 random variables $x,y$, both uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$?
There is no way to find the answer unless you know $f_{xy}(x,y)$. If $x$ and $y$ are actually the same random variable, the answer is that $x+y$ is uniformly random in $[0,2]$. If $x$ and $y$ are independent, then the values of $x+y$ are also in $[0,2]$, but the distribution is centered around $1$, instead of uniform. If $x=1-y$, then $x+y$ isn't random at all, its just alway $1$.
If you wonder what all of this has to do with your transformation problem: $s=x+y, d=x-y$ is also a simple transformation, and as we saw, there is no way to find the distribution of even $s$ alone.
When you say "no new information should be required" for a transformation, that's true. It's just that you don't have the information about your random variable $z=x+iy$, because kompletely knowing that information already includes knowing what $f_{xy}(x,y)$ is.
When you only know the marginal distribitions, that means you only know a certain part of what constitues "knowing the distribution of $x+iy$". Without knowing more, you cannot transfrom this into other variables.

But suppose I know $A$ and $\Theta$ and their marginal distributions and I know they are independent, then I can derive distribution of $x=A\sin \theta$ and $y=A\cos\theta$, But if I know $A$ and $\Theta$ are independent but I do not know the dependency of $x$ and $y$. Then can I transform the random variables from $x+jy$ to $A\exp(j\theta)$?

Please have a look at my edit at the bottom of my post.

That's a much harder question, one I can't help you with. It seems plausible that something like that seems reversible. I suggest making a new question.

As suggested I have made a new post and linked it to this post. Thanks
